# Encrypted partition between Ubuntu 14 and Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, encryption, ubuntu-14.04, open-source

I've created a 50 GB partition (NTFS) for sharing data between Ubuntu 14 and Windows 7. I would like to encrypt this partition in a "common" way between the 2 OS. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Most people would use Truecrypt or any of its variations.  Software recomendations are not on topic, so I won't be submitting an answer, and I believe this question has already been asked.

Comment: Truecrypt develop has ended almost 1 year ago. I was looking for a smart and valid solution for my problem...

Comment: Which is the reason I also suggest "or any of its variations" but my solution must be not be smart.  There are only a couple projects that are actually being worked on that would acomplish your goal.